# How to replace a numerical value in a Python list

Tags: python, list

So I got this list of lists:

```
lst = [[0,1],2,[3]]
```

and I got a list of tuples:

```
lst_2 = [("x1","y1"),("x2","y2"), ("x3","y3"), ("x4","y4")]
```

I want to replace values inside lst with the index 0 value of each of the tuples in lst_2, and the tuple taken depends on the numerical value in lst. So it becomes:

```
lst = [["x1","x2"], "x3", ["x4"]]
```

Please don't roast me thanks so much

Comment: what are the conditions required to fill lst_2 ?

Comment: What if the number of values do not correspond? What if the first list has numbers that are not indices in the second list? What if the first list is more deeply nested? Please explain all the rules to take into account, so to cover boundary cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = [[0,1],2,[3]]
lst_2 = [("x1","y1"),("x2","y2"), ("x3","y3"), ("x4","y4")]

res = []
for l in lst:
    if isinstance(l, list):
        res += [[lst_2[i][0] for i in l]]
    else:
        res += [lst_2[l][0]]
print(res)
```

Or with [`List Comprehensions`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/):

```
res = [[lst_2[i][0] for i in l] if isinstance(l, list) else lst_2[l][0] for l in lst]
```

---

```
[['x1', 'x2'], 'x3', ['x4']]
```

Comment: @rose, You're welcome, If you have a nested list I recommend using [trincot_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75420589/1740577). I want to add a recursive version to my answer that I see `trincot` wrote this ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion to allow `lst` to have deeper levels of nesting:

```
def produce(template, data):
    return [
        produce(nested, data) for nested in template
    ] if isinstance(template, list) else data[template][0]

# Example
lst = [[0,[1]],2,[3]]
lst_2 = [("x1","y1"),("x2","y2"), ("x3","y3"), ("x4","y4")]
result = produce(lst, lst_2)
```

Comment: thank you so much I got an idea for the recursion form now thanks!!